# Django 'memoryview' object has no attribute '_committed'

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am writing app for students project and encountered problem when saving modified model object

Model:

```
class Appointments(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    patient_pesel = models.ForeignKey('Patients', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='patient_pesel')
    appointment_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey('Departments', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='department')
    room = models.ForeignKey('Rooms', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='room', blank=True, null=True)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey('HospitalStaff', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='doctor', blank=True, null=True)
    appointment_type = models.ForeignKey('DAppointmentType', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='appointment_type')
    suggested_date = models.DateField()
    referral = models.FileField(upload_to='referrals', blank=True, null=True)
    nfz = models.BooleanField()
    recommendations = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    accepted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    accepted_by = models.ForeignKey('HospitalStaff', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='accepted_by', blank=True, null=True, related_name='accepted_HospitalStaff')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey('HospitalStaff', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='updated_by', blank=True, null=True, related_name='updated_HospitalStaff')

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'appointments'
```

View:

```
def staff_accept_single_appointment_2(request):
    app_id = request.POST.get("appointment_id")

    date = request.POST.get("app_date")
    time = request.POST.get("app_hour")
    doctor = request.POST.get("doctor")
    room = request.POST.get("room")

    date_time_obj = datetime.strptime((str(date)+' '+str(time)).replace('-','/'), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
    doctor_object = HospitalStaff.objects.get(id=doctor)
    room_object = Rooms.objects.get(room_name=room)

    app_object = Appointments.objects.get(id=app_id)
    app_object.appointment_date=date_time_obj
    app_object.doctor=doctor_object
    app_object.room=room_object

    app_object.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/staff/registration/accept_appointments/accept_single_appointment')
```

also checked much simpler version of view:

```
def staff_accept_single_appointment_2(request):
    app_object = Appointments.objects.get(id=1)
    app_object.save()
```

and i am still encountering 'memoryview' object has no attribute '_committed' error and can not go around it.

Tried also using objects.filter().update() . It does not throws an error, but it does not affect database eighter.

Tried searching solutions, maybe it is connected with FileField in model but i do not understand what is wrong.

Comment: What is `memoryview` and what is trying to access `memoryview._committed` or similar? It looks like there's vital debugging info missing here. If you include your full error/stacktrace that's most helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.